# How to enable cache for node js in travis?

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I'm trying to use bellow syntax:

```
cache:
  bundler: true
  directories:
    - foldername/foldername/node_modules
```

After the build is done I see 11 MB of cache on the 'Cahes' page in Travis, but in real life node_modules is about 60 mb and I can't say that I have some perfomance improvment.
Is it ok or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If your build logs are public, please provide a link here. If not, you might want to try your luck at support@travis-ci.com.

Comment: I've already written to support, hope they will help, thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have cached my folders for nodejs.

```
# .travis.yml

language: node_js

node_js:
  - "stable"

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
```

Note: Folders located under `directories` are relative to the `.travis.yml` file.

The [official documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#Enabling-multiple-caching-features) has more information.